# What's the Mathematica command for $\frac{\partial^a}{\partial n^a}\binom{n}{k}$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

What's the Mathematica command for

$$f(a,n,k)=\frac{\partial^a}{\partial n^a}\binom{n}{k}$$

I tried

```
f[a_,n_,k_]:=D[Binomial[n,k], {n,a}]
```

but didn't work. To make it work, I had to use

```
f[a_]:=D[Binomial[n,k], {n,a}]
```

then I picked a value for $a$ (`f[2]` for example) to get a function in terms of $n$ and $k$ then I selected values for $n$ and $k$.

Is there one-line command for this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you face is, that you must evaluate the derivative relative to n before n is replaced by an argument. One way to achieve this is by using an additional variable: n1. E.g.:

```
f[a_, n_, k_] := D[Binomial[n1, k],{n1,a}] /. n1 -> n
```

with this:

```
f[1, 5, 3]
(* 47/6*)
```

Comment: Thanks Dan thats what I'm looking for (+1).

Comment: I think you meant `D[Binomial[n1, k], {n1, a}]`

Comment: Yes that's right. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
Derivative[a, 0][Function[{nn, kk}, Binomial[nn, kk]]][n, k]
```

or

```
Derivative[a, 0][Binomial][n, k] (Thanks @CarlWoll )
```

$\frac{1}{2} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 a! \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & a=2 \\
 2 n-1 & a=1 \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right) & a\geq 1 \\
 (n-1) n & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Simpler is `Derivative[a, 0][Binomial][n, k]`

Comment: @AliShadhar See my modified answer

Comment: Got it. I also see @bmf's code is simple as well. thank you guys

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it: use [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) rather than [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)

```
g[a_, n_, k_] = D[Binomial[n, k], {n, a}];
```

The first derivative

```
g[1, 5, 3]
```

> [image: 476]

The second

```
g[2, 5, 3]
```

> [image: 4]

Comment: (+1)  This is a typical example, why it is better to use Set, whereever you can, instead of SetDelayed as a standard. I often said.